# Hiding an entry (or a "fin the registry

Tags: winapi, registry

I'm trying to hide some values in the registry (such as serial numbers) with C++/windows
so I've been looking at this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/NtRegistry.aspx
which says:

> How is this possible? The answer is
>   that a name which is a counted as a
>   Unicode string can explicitly include
>   NULL characters (0) as part of the
>   name. For example, "Key\0". To include
>   the NULL at the end, the length of the
>   Unicode string is specified as 4.
>   There is absolutely no way to specify
>   this name using the Win32 API since if
>   "Key\0" is passed as a name, the API
>   will determine that the name is "Key"
>   (3 characters in length) because the
>   "\0" indicates the end of the name.
>
> When a key (or any other object with a
>   name such as a named Event, Semaphore,
>   or Mutex) is created with such a name,
>   any application using the Win32 API
>   will be unable to open the name, even
>   though they might seem to see it.

so I tried doing something similar:

```
HKEY keyHandle;
PHKEY key;
unsigned long status = 0;

wchar_t *wKeyName = new wchar_t[m_keyLength];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, m_keyName, m_keyLength, wKeyName, m_keyLength);
wKeyName[18] = '\0';
long result = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                              wKeyName,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              0,
                              KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                              NULL,
                              &keyHandle,
                              &status);
```

where `m_keyName` is the ASCII text and wKeyName is the wide char text, but in `regedit` I see that it is treated the same and the key is just cut where I put the '\0'.

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the Win32 API and not the NT Native API.  There is a table about 1/2 way through [the article that you referenced](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/NtRegistry.aspx) that contains the list of Native APIs.  For example, you would use [`NtCreateKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556468%29v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`ZwCreateKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `RegCreateKeyExW`.  The Win32 API assumes that alls strings are terminated by a NUL character whereas the Native API counterparts use a [`UNICODE_STRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564879%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure for the name.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab in the dark, as I have never tried to do this.

It appears that you are using the wrong function to create your registry key. You should be using the `NtCreateKey` method because `RegCreateKeyEx`[AW] will notice your `'\0'` and chop off past it.

Why not use the class provided in the example? It provides a method called `CreateHiddenKey`. To use it, simply call `SetKey` before it. It would be much cleaner.